# Customising space between flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am almost fine with the result given by `justify-content: space-between`, I just would like to have less space between the last two flex items.

I tried to `calc()` a negative left margin for the last item, but it doesn't fully work: on my browser in full screen, the last two items are separated by more than the supposed `1em` calculated, then while shrinking the window, they get closer till they touch. And with further shrinking the last items bounces away.

```css
.belt {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1em;
}

.belt > * {
  min-width: 10em;
  border: solid orange;
}

.belt > button {
  margin-left: calc((42em - 100%) / 3 + 1em);
}
```

```html
<div class='belt'>
  <a href='/'>LOGO</a>
  <div>[_______________|Q]</div>
  <a href='/signin'>Sign in</a>
  <button>Cart</button>
</div>
```

The calculation I made:

- To make the calculation possible in first place I had to define a width for the items and I used `min-width: 10em;` which also works as a `width` because the content of the items is less than `10em`
- `100%` minus the `40em` of the four items, minus the two `1em` paddings of the container, divided by `3` (the spaces between four items) ---> should be more or less the space between the items when using `justify-content: space-between`
- setting the left margin of the last item to a negative value being the result of the expression above should result on having no space between the last two items
- final step: adding `1em`

What's wrong with this approach and what would be a good way to achieve a `1em` space between the last two items?

PS: I came to know about this [gap](https://caniuse.com/flexbox-gap) property, which unfortunately wouldn't reach 99% of Safari users, so for now is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can simply use `margin:auto` on the second item and your `1em` margin on the last item:

```css
.belt {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1em;
}

.belt > * {
  min-width: 10em;
  border: solid orange;
}

.belt > button {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.belt > div {
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='belt'>
  <a href='/'>LOGO</a>
  <div>[_______________|Q]</div>
  <a href='/signin'>Sign in</a>
  <button>Cart</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am going to accept it as the answer because it works for me. However this `magin: auto` approach works only if you need at most three equidistant item. It is not a general solution for these kind of problems.

Comment: @SheikYerbouti if you have more items, you apply margin:auto to all the element but not the first, the last and the before the last

Comment: Your are right, I don't why I supposed `margin:auto` to not work for multiple items. Well that's nice!